# SOAP XSD Root Element Issue

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, ws

Whenever I create my XSD element name: Ansh, it(wsdl) doesnt get loaded in my SOAPUI(Soapui doesnt create operation for this request) bu when i change my element name as: AnshRequest, request template is generated.

```
    <xsd:element name="Ansh">
       <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="SignonRq" type="tns:SignonRq" />
                <xsd:element name="BillerSvcRq" type="tns:BillerSvcRq" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

This works fine: when i change rootelement as AnshRequest:

```
    <xsd:element name="AnshRequest">
       <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="SignonRq" type="tns:SignonRq" />
                <xsd:element name="BillerSvcRq" type="tns:BillerSvcRq" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

SOAP UI:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:acc="http://accountupload.atheeb.net">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:AnshRequest>
         <acc:SignonRq>
            <acc:ClientDt>4</acc:ClientDt>
            <acc:LanguagePref>?</acc:LanguagePref>
         </acc:SignonRq>
         <acc:BillerSvcRq>
            <acc:StatusCode>1</acc:StatusCode>
            <acc:RqUID>uuid</acc:RqUID>
         </acc:BillerSvcRq>
      </acc:AnshRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help, i am new to SOAP WS. I want only "Ansh" to be the root element.

Comment: You're having issues with a WSDL, but decided to ask without showing the relevant parts of the WSDL? Hmmm...

Comment: Where is your content and c# classes defined?  The response, content, and classes have to be consistent.  You can add an attribute to the class [XmlRoot("AnshRequest")] so the class Ansh will recognize the xml tag AnshRequest.